# Who's מרן and what book is ד״ח in דברי יואל?

Tags: jewish-books, satmar

The fourth responsum in [volume 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20289&pgnum=51) (*Orach Chayim*) of Rabbi *Yoel* Teitelbaum's *Divre Yoel* refers (near its start) to "פסקו של מרן ז״ל בד״ח ח״ב סי׳ ו׳", "the ruling of our master's (OBM) in D.Ch. volume 2 chapter 6". What author and work are referred to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find it inside, but it's quoted [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_49833_387.pdf) as coming from Rabbi Chaim of Tzanz.

**EDIT**

Found it!!

It's [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=913&st=&pgnum=111&hilite=), Shu"t Divrei Chaim of R' Chaim of Tzanz Orach Chaim Chelek Beis Siman Vov.